# How to use struct in a function

Tags: c, struct

```
typedef struct node {
    int num_children;
    struct node *children[ALPHABET_LENGTH];
} trie_node;

void add(char* a, trie_node* node){//need to make sure a is not NULL at beginning
    trie_node* newNode;
    int i;
    if (a != NULL && node->children[(int)a[0] - 97] == NULL)
    {
        node->num_children++;
        //initialize the children array
        for (i = 0; i < ALPHABET_LENGTH; i++)
        {
            if (newNode->children[i] != NULL)
            {
                newNode->children[i] = NULL;
            }
        }
        newNode -> num_children = 0;
        a++;
        add(a, newNode);
    }
    else if (a != NULL && node->children[(int)a[0] - 97] != NULL){
        a++;
        node->num_children++;
        add(a, node->children[(int)a[0] - 97]);
    } else{//a == NULL, which means end of the add procedure
        return;
    }
}


int main()
{
        char* s = "add abc";
        trie_node* contacts;
        add(s,contacts);
        return 0;
}
```

When I intialize the struct trie_node in main function, I can access all member of contacts. However, when I do that in my add function, the newNode doesn't work. I cannot access members like num_children under newNode. How could I fix that if I want to add a new node to the contacts

Comment: You never ever set `newnode` to any value. Nor do you set `contacts` before passing it to the function. Your code has Undefined Behaviour all over it.

Comment: C or C++? Make up your mind.

Comment: Also you haven't set `contacts`

Comment: Please try to avoid [*magic numbers*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Magic_number_(programming)). If you mean the character `'a'` then say so instead of using `97`. Also note that what you are doing with `a[0] - 97` (or `a[0] - 'a'`) is not portable, not all systems use [ASCII](http://en.cppreference.com/w/c/language/ascii), or even encodings where letters are consecutive. Lastly you don't need the cast to `int`, the compiler will implicitly do it for you (read about [usual arithmetic conversions](http://en.cppreference.com/w/c/language/conversion#Usual_arithmetic_conversions))

Comment: C or C++? Decide and then remove the other tag.

Comment: If a question applies equally well to C and the subset of C++ that is essentially ANSI C 89, I see no reason why one cannot have both C and C++ tag on a question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You don't allocate any stoarge to `contacts` or set it to `NULL` in `main` or test if it is null in `add`.

If you are lucky, because you are right at the start of the program, `contacts` is NULL when you pass it in, so the if test at the top of `add` crashes with a segmentation violation.

Also, you use `newNode` without allocating space to it.